# How to get backend json error from the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

Iam trying to build a web application that takes data from the admin and save it in the database (MongoDB).
I made an API Error Class to handle the errors of the app and send the error message in JSON. All what i need is working right. but when the error happens it display the JSON rather than the web page. I need a way to handle it with the vanilla JS. so when the error happens and the server side send the error message in JSON it takes it and display the error message inside maybe a paragraph.
I will show you the server side codes put it's in a different files so ill put it as parts. **The check happens after the form submitted.**

apiError.js :

```
class ApiError extends Error{
    constructor(message,statusCode){
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = `${statusCode} `.startsWith(4)?'fail' : 'error';
        this.isOperational = true;
    }
}

module.exports = ApiError;
```

errorMiddleware.js:

```
const globalError = (err,req,res,next)=>{
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
    err.status = err.status || "error";
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
        sendErrorForDev(err,res);
    }else{
        sendErrorForProd(err,res);
    }
}


const sendErrorForDev = (err,res)=>{
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status : err.status,
        error: err,
        message: err.message,
        stack: err.stack
    });
};

const sendErrorForProd = (err,res)=>{
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        status : err.status,
        message: err.message,
    });
}

module.exports = globalError;
```

clientService.js:

```
exports.addClient = asyncHandler(async(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body.number);
    const client = await ClientModel.findOne({number: req.body.number});
    if(!client){
        const name = req.body.name;
        const report = {
            patientName:req.body.patientName || name,
            R:{
                rdSph:req.body.rdSph,
                rdCyl:req.body.rdCyl,
                rdAxis:req.body.rdAxis,
                rrSph:req.body.rrSph,
                rrCyl:req.body.rrCyl,
                rrAxis:req.body.rrAxis
            },
            L:{
                ldSph:req.body.ldSph,
                ldCyl:req.body.ldCyl,
                ldAxis:req.body.ldAxis,
                lrSph:req.body.lrSph,
                lrCyl:req.body.lrCyl,
                lrAxis:req.body.lrAxis
            },
            pd:req.body.pd,
            date: `${today.getDate()} ${today.getMonth()} ${today.getFullYear()}`
        };
            await ClientModel.create({
                name:name,
                number:req.body.number,
                report:report
            });
            console.log("Success");
            res.redirect("/admin/api/addClient")
    }else{
        return next(new ApiError("User Already Exists",400));
    }
});
```

clientRoute.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const {addClient,
    displayAddClient} = require('../services/clientService');
    
    const router = express.Router()
router.route("/addClient").get(displayAddClient).post(addClient);
module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
app.use("/admin/api",clientRoute);

app.all("*",(req,res,next)=>{
    next(new ApiError(`Can't find this route: ${req.originalUrl}`,400));
})

// Gloval Error Handling Middleware
app.use(globalError);
```

I tried to use fetch in vanilla JS but it didn't catch the JSON